# I converted a video mp4 file to audio mp3 format and now I want to remove the original Mp4 video file using os.remove but giving error

Tags: python, module, operating-system

Previously, I converted a mp4 video file to a mp3 audio file. Now I would now like to remove the orginial mp4 video file using

```
os.remove
```

However, when I execute my code, it shows me an error as follows:

```
Win32 error : The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process
```

Below is my code:

```
try:
    global stram
    b2.config(text="Please wait...")
    b2.config(state=DISABLED)
    stream = yt.streams.filter(progressive=True)
    path = filedialog.askdirectory()
    if path == None:
        return
    stream[0].download(path)
    for i in os.listdir(path):
        os.rename(os.path.join(path,i),os.path.join(path,i.replace(' ','_')))
    title = yt.title.replace(' ','_')
    video = VideoFileClip(os.path.join(path+"/"+title+".mp4"))
    video.audio.write_audiofile(os.path.join(path+"/"+title+".mp3"))

    l3 = Label(action,text="Download Complete",font=("Calibri",12),fg = "green").pack()
    b2.config(text="Download Audio")
    try:
        file = str(f'{title}.mp4')
        os.remove(os.path.join(path,file))
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
except Exception as e:
    l3 = Label(action,text="Error occured while Downloading",font=("Calibri",12),fg = "red").pack()
```

Does anyone know why this error occurs? Your help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try using shutil.rmtree(filepath). [Shutil](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am no expert when it comes to windows but I think by "another process" it is actually referring to your python script, or the module you are using within your python script. My guess would be that you should find a way to close the `video` variable.

Based on [this](https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/issues/653) you should be able to do `video.close()` before `os.remove`.